# No installed ConfigArgs for the service

Tags: php, apache

I have installed Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6.18 individually on windows 7 32 bit.
I have modified `httpd.conf,`php.ini` files as needed.

While starting the Apache service i am getting the error as "

> The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>
> [Thu Mar 17 14:18:43.923600 2016] [mpm_winnt:warn] [pid 11936:tid 252] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : AH00435: No installed ConfigArgs for the service "ZSA_Apache24 Server", using Apache defaults.

Any idea why i am getting this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I got the exact same error message after installing a "CollabNet Subversion Apache" server. That's a bundle from CollabNet with Apache and Subversion preconfigured. It comes with a Windows installer which sets everything up, including a Windows service named "CollabNet Subversion Apache".

I've researched this issue and found that there must be something wrong with the Windows service. Probably it's an issue with how the installer installed the service.

What finally solved the issue for me was uninstalling the Windows service and reinstalling it. Afterwards everything was just fine.

To do that, open a command line and navigate to where you installed Apache. Go into the `bin` directory, where `httpd.exe` is located. From there call:

```
httpd.exe -k uninstall -n "ZSA_Apache24 Server"
httpd.exe -k install -n "ZSA_Apache24 Server"
```

`ZSA_Apache24 Server` is the name of the Windows service running your Apache server.

Documentation of these commands can be found here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#winsvc